# How to define a weak variable within a Swift guard statement

Tags: ios, swift

How do I change the following closure so that `cell` is 'weak'? :

```
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? PlayerTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PlayerTableViewCell")
        }
```

I am sure there is a simple way to achieve this but I have been unable to determine the correct way to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need a weak reference to a cell in your `cellForRowAt` method?

Comment: That's just a `guard` statement, not a closure expression.

Comment: @maddy - I ran the Inspection tool and found that this statement was not releasing the `cell` object from memory and a number of instances of `cell` are hanging around in memory. My research suggests I need to make `cell` weak so it gets released from memory after use.

Comment: @Hamish - thanks for the comment. I've updated the subject line

Comment: Isn't it expected that cells returned by dequeueReusableCell will be retained by the table view for eventual reuse? In other words, your variable may not be what's retaining the cells.

Comment: You should update your question with a bit more context. Show more code. And using `guard` here is somewhat pointless. Just force-cast the cell to the expected type. If it's the wrong type you want it to crash so you can fix the code.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson - *facepalm* your comment just had something click into place and I spotted a duplicate call to`dequeueReusableCell` nested within a call to another method which was causing the memory issue. So, you and @maddy were right - no need to make this weak. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A duplicate call to `dequeueReusableCell` was causing a memory consumption problem, which led me to think I had a strong reference that needed to be weakened.

Removing this erroneous extra call solved the underlying issue I thought needed a fix.